# How to creat copy alerts to many buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, dynamic-html

Hey am new to java script But putting my all efforts I have written a javascript to copy a text inside `<p></p>` But needed a alert text to be visible when the "copy" button is clicked. And mainly I have many buttons.My javascript

```
function copyToClipboard(var1){
  let val = document.getElementById(var1).innerHTML;
  const selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
  selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
  selBox.style.left = '0';
  selBox.style.top = '0';
  selBox.style.opacity = '0';
  selBox.value = val;
  document.body.appendChild(selBox);
  selBox.focus();
  selBox.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(selBox);
}
```

My html

```
<div class="englishstatus">
       <div class="car">
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p9">life os good when hou have books</p> 
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p9')">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p10">Google is a open source library. It is a open source by lary page and sergy brime</p>
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p10')">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p11">Cat is better than dog</p>
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p11')">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p12">Cat is better than dog</p>
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p12')">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

The Copied alert in my html code is  `<span class="copystatusalert">Copied!</span>`.I needed this element to be visible for some seconds when I click the respective copy button and be vanished after few seconds. Please help me and thanks in advance.

```js
function copyToClipboard(var1){
  let val = document.getElementById(var1).innerHTML;
  const selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
  selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
  selBox.style.left = '0';
  selBox.style.top = '0';
  selBox.style.opacity = '0';
  selBox.value = val;
  document.body.appendChild(selBox);
  selBox.focus();
  selBox.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(selBox);
}
```

```html
<div class="englishstatus">
       <div class="car">
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p9">life os good when hou have books</p> 
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p9')">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p10">Google is a open source library. It is a open source by lary page and sergy brime</p>
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p10')">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p11">Cat is better than dog</p>
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p11')">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p12">Cat is better than dog</p>
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p12')">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: that fragment of html has an unbalanced number of opening/closing `DIV` tags.

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet below we:

- pass the button where the click occurred
- find the span near it
- hide it
- schedule its showing in a few seconds
- design the .invisible class

```js
function copyToClipboard(var1, btn){
  let val = document.getElementById(var1).innerHTML;
  const selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
  selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
  selBox.style.left = '0';
  selBox.style.top = '0';
  selBox.style.opacity = '0';
  selBox.value = val;
  document.body.appendChild(selBox);
  selBox.focus();
  selBox.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(selBox);
  let item = btn.parentNode.querySelector(".invisible");
  if (item) {
      item.classList.remove("invisible");
      setTimeout(function() {
          item.classList.add("invisible");
      }, 4000);
  }
}
```

```css
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="englishstatus">
       <div class="car">
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p9">life os good when hou have books</p> 
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p9', this)">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert invisible">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p10">Google is a open source library. It is a open source by lary page and sergy brime</p>
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p10', this)">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert invisible">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p11">Cat is better than dog</p>
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p11', this)">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert invisible">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p12">Cat is better than dog</p>
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p12', this)">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert invisible">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refactor your code slightly you can make this all work without needing to use IDs in the calls to the main function and can use an externally registered event handler which, to my mind, is a much cleaner way to approaching this.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

  const createtextbox=function(text){
    let el=document.createElement('textarea');
      el.style.position = 'fixed';
      el.style.left = '0';
      el.style.top = '0';
      el.style.opacity = '0';
      el.value = text;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    return el;
  };

  const shortmessage=function(e,m,t){
    let span=e.parentNode.querySelector( 'span' );
      span.innerText=m;
    setTimeout(()=>{span.innerText=''},1000 * t)
  };

  const copytoclipboard=function(e){
    // create the hidden textarea and add the text from the sibling element
    let n=createtextbox( this.parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML );
      n.focus();
      n.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(n);

    // flash a message in the SPAN-clear after 2s
    shortmessage( this, 'Copied!', 2 );
  };

  /*
    Find a reference to ALL buttons that are used to copy
    text from a sibling element and assign an event handler 
    to process every button click.
  */
  document.querySelectorAll('button.copystatus').forEach( bttn=>{
    bttn.addEventListener( 'click', copytoclipboard )
  });
})
```

```html
<!--
  In many instances there is no need to assign IDs to DOM elements in
  order to target them programmatically. There are many methods native
  to Javascript to navigate through the DOM - parent/child/sibling 
  selectors and when used in conjunction with an `Event` you can easily
  locate items of interest.
-->
<div class='englishstatus'>
  <div class='car'>
    <div class='latestatus'>
      <p>Life is good when you have books</p> 
      <button class='copystatus btn'>Copy</button>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class='latestatus'>
      <p>Google is a open source library by Larry Page and Sergey Brin!</p>
      <button class='copystatus btn'>Copy</button>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='car'>
    <div class='latestatus'>
      <p>Cats are better than dogs.</p>
      <button class='copystatus btn'>Copy</button>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class='latestatus'>
      <p>Ferrets are better than rats</p>
      <button class='copystatus btn'>Copy</button>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```